# How to Add OrganizationToken to WCF Endpoint in code

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I am trying to connect to a SOAP API of a vendor and I have a sample project they provided which works.  I am trying to figure out how to replace their endpoint which is in the app.config with one created in code so I can load endpoint URL, username, and password using DI.

Here is the relevant XML from the app.config:

`<client>
      <endpoint address="https://strongmail.com/sm/services/mailing/v2" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MailingServiceServiceSoapBinding" contract="MailingService" name="MailingServicePort">
        <headers>
          <SOAP-ENV:Header xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
            <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
              <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken">
                <wsse:Username>Username</wsse:Username>
                <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">Password</wsse:Password>
              </wsse:UsernameToken>
              <OrganizationToken xmlns="http://www.strongmail.com/services/v2/schema">
                <organizationName>admin</organizationName>
                <subOrganizationId>
                  <id>1</id>
                </subOrganizationId>
              </OrganizationToken>
            </wsse:Security>
          </SOAP-ENV:Header>
        </headers>
      </endpoint>

    </client>`

This is the code I am trying to use to instantiate this.

```
public class SelligentOrganizationToken
    {
        public string organizationName { get; set; }
        public SelligentOrganization subOrganizationId { get; set; }
    }

    public class SelligentOrganization
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
    }

    private MailingService CreateMailingService(string mailingServiceUrl, string userName, string password)
    {

        var securityElement = SecurityBindingElement.CreateUserNameOverTransportBindingElement();
        securityElement.IncludeTimestamp = false;
        var encodingElement = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement(MessageVersion.Soap11, Encoding.UTF8);
        var transportElement = new HttpsTransportBindingElement();

        var customBinding = new CustomBinding(securityElement, encodingElement, transportElement);

        var remoteAddress = new EndpointAddress(mailingServiceUrl);

        var mailingService = new MailingServiceClient(customBinding, remoteAddress);

        mailingService.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = userName;
        mailingService.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = password;

        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls11;

        var selligentOrganizationToken = new SelligentOrganizationToken()
        {
            organizationName = "admin",
            subOrganizationId = new SelligentOrganization()
            {
                id = "1"
            }
        };

        //Serialize object to xml
        XmlObjectSerializer xmlObjectSerializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(SelligentOrganizationToken), "OrganizationToken", "http://www.strongmail.com/services/v2/schema");

        var eab = new EndpointAddressBuilder(mailingService.Endpoint.Address);
        eab.Headers.Add(AddressHeader.CreateAddressHeader("OrganizationToken", "http://www.strongmail.com/services/v2/schema", selligentOrganizationToken, xmlObjectSerializer));
        mailingService.Endpoint.Address = eab.ToEndpointAddress();

        return mailingService;
    }
```

When I try to run this I am getting:

System.ServiceModel.FaultException: 'A security error was encountered when verifying the message'

Which, incidentally, is what I get when running the example code if I remove the OrganizationToken node.

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I see you app.config has configured headers node and it seems you are not using the endpointconfig. Instead, you  add headers in your c# code.

How about directly use the  endpoint configuration in your app.config?

```
var mailingService = new MailingServiceClient("MailingServicePort")
```

If you want to add addressHeader, you could also try to use OutgoingMessageHeaders or HttpRequestMessageProperty.
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/How-to-add-custom-5cbbf066

Please ensure where you want to add the header, OutgoingMessageHeaders is used to add a soap header and HttpRequestMessageProperty is used to add a header in request header.

Comment: The key is this sentence: "I am trying to figure out how to replace their endpoint which is in the app.config with one created in code so I can load endpoint URL, username, and password using DI".  When I create the endpoint using the configuration in the app.config I find that I am unable to set the username and password.  I would have expected this line of code to do it: mailingService.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = userName; but I think it isn't working because the credentials are in the wsse:username node.  Regardless I couldn't figure out how to set it.